# Recursively updating date format in file path

Tags: python, datetime

I am writing a script that will iterate through a directory with 20 sub directories each with 12 sub directories containing 365 .tar files. Each file has a structure like this: `MODIS_20050301.tar,MODIS_20050302.tar,...,MODIS_20050331.tar`

The goal is to change the format of each folder to this:
`MODIS_2005-03-01.tar,MODIS_2005-03-02.tar,...,MODIS_2005-03-31.tar`

I have written a test script to try and implement this before I run it on each of the total 6850 files but am running into a `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'MODIS_20050527.txt' -> 'MODIS_2005-05-27.txt'`

I created a test directory `Fake\` which has a two sub directories `Fake\Year\Month` which contain my two test files `MODIS_20050527` and `MODIS_20050528` as `.txt` files.

Below is the script I implemented to do this task but again am running into the `FileNotFoundError` I am curious if my `dir` variable is wrong or if there is an issue in my `for` loop.

```
dir = r"XXX\Fake"

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
    for name in files:
        string = 'MODIS_'
        ext = '.txt'
        d = datetime.datetime.strptime(name[7:15],'%Y%m%d').date()
        new_name = string + str(d) + ext
        os.rename(name,new_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Implementing a solution from ["Python loop through folders and rename files"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38907645/python-loop-through-folders-and-rename-files) I believe I found the solution. The issue being the root of the file. An update to my code now looks like this:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
    for name in files:
        string = 'SNODAS_'
        #ext = '.txt'
        d = datetime.datetime.strptime(name[7:15],'%Y%m%d').date()
        new_name = string + str(d)
        os.rename(os.path.join(root,name),os.path.join(root,new_name))
```

I am a bit confused now though as to whether I need to include the `ext` variable or not I ran it both times with and without it and the resulting name change was the same. IE `MODIS_2005-05-27`.

Answer (score 0):

`name` is just the name of each file, but `os.rename` needs the full path.

You have the remainder of the path in `root` from `os.walk`, so you just need to join this to the old and new file names in the last line of the `for` loop.

Change the last line to:

```
os.rename(os.path.join(root, name), os.path.join(root, new_name))
```

Also covered in this answer:

[Need the path for particular files using os.walk()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16465399/need-the-path-for-particular-files-using-os-walk)

By the way, I had to change `[7:15]` to `[7:14]` to get the code to run correctly.